# Unable to Update Progress UI using AsyncTask

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a `MapActivity` in my android application and I want to draw a route from source to destination followed by drawing `polyline` along the path found. I am showing a `progressDialog` while `polyline` is drawn along the path.

I think drawing polyline is a heavy task as it caused `progressDialog` to stop spinning. So I put `drawPolyline` functionality inside an `AsyncTask`.

But the problem I am facing now is I am not getting updated screen but suddenly the `MapActivity` screen blinks and disappear and I see the MainActivity now.

Why is it happening?
**I want to know whether or not updating UI in the background of AsyncTask is conceptually correct?** If yes, how can we go about doing it?

**Note:** I have checked AsyncTask functionality by putting breakPoints. It is working as expected but drawPolyline causes error.
Also drawPolyline has no problem as it works fine when called without AsyncTask.

Here is my AsyncTask code:

```
public class DrawRoute {

    private WeatherMapActivity listener;
    private GoogleMap mMap = WeatherMapActivity.mMap;
    private List<Step> stepsInThePath = WeatherMapActivity.stepsInThePath;

    public DrawRoute(WeatherMapActivity listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        Log.d("imHere", "in the DrawRouteConstructor");
    }

    public void execute(){
        Log.d("imHere", "in the execute of DrawRoute");
        new DrawPolyline().execute();
    }

    private class DrawPolyline extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("imHere", "in the PreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Log.d("imHere", "in the Background");
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(listener, Locale.getDefault());

            mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(stepsInThePath.get(0).startLocation, stepsInThePath.get(0).endLocation)
                    .width(8)
                    .color(Color.RED));

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(MainActivity.sourceAddress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_red))
                    .position(stepsInThePath.get(0).startLocation));

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(MainActivity.destinationAddress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                    .position(stepsInThePath.get(stepsInThePath.size()-1).endLocation));


            for(int i=1; i < stepsInThePath.size(); i++){
                mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(stepsInThePath.get(i-1).endLocation, stepsInThePath.get(i).endLocation)
                        .width(8)
                        .color(Color.RED));

                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(stepsInThePath.get(i).startLocation.latitude, stepsInThePath.get(i).startLocation.longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

                if(i%5 == 0 || i == stepsInThePath.size()-1){
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .title(cityName)
                            .position(stepsInThePath.get(i).startLocation));
                }
            }

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(stepsInThePath.get(0).startLocation, 5));

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("imHere", "in the PostExecute");
//            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Any kind of suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Add your `AsyncTask ` code .

Comment: @ADM I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never attempt to update a UI element directly from `doInBackground()` method. The purpose of `doInBackground()` is to not block the UI by running in a separate thread to offload some of the work from main thread (UI thread).
So instead, from `doInBackground()`, call `publishProgress()` to pass your progress to `onProgressUpdate()` function to do UI stuff.

Comment: That is exactly I wanted to ask. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` is meant to run in background and **No other thread can update the UI other then MainThread**.

What you can do it do all calculation in `doInBackground()` and return it . Then Draw in `onPostExecute()`. Or you can use a MainThread handler to draw from `doInBackground()`.

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

OR

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPostExecute() method to make any changes to ui, so you don't have to create a method for that.